# Adding different types of geometry to layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, geometry, geopackage, vector-layer

How can I combine points and lines in a layer?

Currently, I'm using a GeoPackage layer but when creating this new layer you need to define what geometry type you want to use.

So is it not possible to map points and draw a line or square in the same layer?

Comment: You can add multilple layers with different geometries to a single geopackage.

Comment: If you need to do that kind of editing you could try OpenJUMP that can handle all kind of geometries in the same layer. Unfortunately OpenJUMP can save such layers only into the native JML format or as GeoJSON. However, with ogr2ogr it is possible to save JML or GeoJSON into GeoPackage and keep all the geometries in one table that is usign a generic GeoPackage geometry type "geometry".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you mean adding them to a QGIS layer, the answer is 'No'. It is not possible. This is the nature of the QGIS layer. But somehow (maybe by a script) you may export layers, which have different geometry type, to a single file which supports multiple geometry types.

But when you load the exported file to QGIS, it will split the different geometries into different layers.

If you mean adding them to a GeoPackage layer, the answer is still 'No'. You can add different geometry types to a GeoPackage but as different layers, not as one layer.

Comment: ok, thanks, as I just wanted to be 100% sure as what I understood from a GeoPackage it was possible but this refers to the file format itself. ok.